# Odd Behavior From Query

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I can't seem to figure out why this query works only if john is below a.

Chat Table

```
**chatid**      **username**
   132              john
```

Test Table

```
**chatid**       **username**
   132               john
   132               a
```

Query

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp ( ids INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,id Int NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO tmp (id) VALUES (132);
SELECT  i.id, IFNULL(COUNT(ta.chatid),0), count(l.chatid),IFNULL(x.username, '@')
FROM tmp i 
inner JOIN chat ta ON ta.chatid = i.id
left JOIN test l ON ta.chatid = l.chatid
left  JOIN chat x ON (x.chatid = l.chatid and x.username = l.username)
                 
GROUP BY i.id
ORDER BY i.ids asc;
```

Chat to test table is a one to many relationship.  The query only works correctly depending on the order of test table.  For example if john is below a it will display john  which is correct.  However, if john is above a then the query results in a null username which is incorrect (should still display john).

Goal: I'm trying to display x.username only if he exists in both chat and test table otherwise display null(@).  I need this to work without messing up the counts in the select statement

Comment: Both tsql and MySQL???

Comment: @jarlh the only difference in syntax is the temp table which is irrelevant to the part of the query in question.  So I figured anyone with knowledge in tsql can help too?

Comment: until the solution is not tsql. You aren't on msft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You outer-join x, so for some records x.username may be filled and for some it may be null. You group by `i.id` and select `x.username`. But there can be many user names for one id, even NULLs as in your example. You don't tell the DBMS which of these you want (e.g. the last username in the alphabet), so the DBMS picks one arbitrarily. NULL in your case. Bad luck, but you left it to chance, so don't complain ;-)

I don't know what exactly you want to achieve. Your example is too small for me to understand precisely what the query is supposed to do. But anyway, when aggregating, tell the DBMS which value to pick. `IFNULL(MIN(x.username), '@')` would do the trick here (but I cannot tell if the query does exactly what you want it to do).

Is this what you are after: Count all occurences for a chatid in test and display the username only when it exists in the test records?

```
select 
  c.chatid, 
  count(t.chatid),
  case when max(t.username = c.username) then c.username else '@' end
from chat c 
left join test t on t.chatid = c.chatid
where c.chatid in (select id from tmp)
group by c.chatid;
```

Comment: How can I not leave it up to chance?  since its a one to many relationship, how can I attempt to output john if theres 10 different usernames in any order in test with the same id?  The min would only output john if he is the first username?

Comment: I've added a query that might meet your needs. I am not completely sure it does, though, as I am rather guessing your intentions here.

Comment: It worked!  Can you help me understand what the max is doing in your query?

Comment: I am using MySQL booelan logic here. For every record pair where `t.username = c.username` matches this expression is true = 1, for every other name it is false = 0. `MAX(t.username = c.username)` is hence 1 = true in case that at least one record pair had matching names. In this case I display `c.username` (which is unique for a c.chatid, so I don't need an aggregate function such as `MIN(c.username)` here). Otherwise I display '@'. Hope this clarifies it.